# Debugging Native DLL Registered as a Service

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, service

I am developing a native DLL service for a directshow filter, and I am registering it as following:

```
regsvr32.exe service.dll
```

The library is being invoked by another application, say viewer.exe

I tried to use Attach to Process option in visual studio 2013, with "Show Process from All Users" checked. However I couldn't find the library "service.dll" listed. I tried to attach to "viewer.exe", however I couldn't get the debugger working with the library I need to debug.

Is there any workarounds this problem, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use Project > Properties > Debugging > Command and select the .exe that needs to run to debug your DLL.  Change the Debugger Type if necessary, "Native Only" is usually the correct choice for C++ code.  Press F5 to start.  You cannot debug anything as long as the DLL does not get loaded, visible both in the Output window and the Debug > Windows > Modules debugger window.

Comment: Thank you! My mistake!!

I was trying to debug it before the application actually loads it, that's why the symbols were not getting loaded! ><